# Dump HLO IR for TPU while using TPUClusterResolver

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I'm using TPU through Google Colab and GCP, and want to dump XLA IR. But I have seen the xla doc in github [xla index](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/g3doc/index.md), and it only shows the way while the backend is CPU or GPU.

I have tried using `XLA_FLAGS="--xla_dump_hlo_as_text --xla_dump_to=/content/iir/" TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit` to run a CPU-targeted program and get dumped hlo file. I have also tried `capture_tpu_file` and can only get ir for each operator in 'op_profile' page. So is there a way to dump XLA IR for the whole program when the backend is TPU?

Thank you!

Jay

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to dump/access the XLA IR on Cloud TPUs at the moment, since the XLA_FLAGS need to be set on the TPU server.

Comment: So we can't dump HLO IR when the target is TPU, even before any optimizations? If that's true, can we use functions in [libtpu_client.c](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/compiler/xla/python/tpu_driver/client/libtpu_client.c) to run HLO IR dumped when the backend is CPU or GPU?